DP module no attribute
How to fix the attribute error?
banned_users = set()
@dp.message_handler(user_id=banned_users)
async def handle_banned(msg: Message):
    print(f"{msg.from_user.full_name} пишет, но мы ему не ответим!")
    return True


@dp.message_handler()
async def handle_all(msg: Message):
    await msg.reply(f"Добрый день, {msg.from_user.full_name} :)")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['ban'], user_id=1581922908)  # здесь укажи свой ID
async def handle_ban_command(msg: Message):
    # проверяем, что ID передан правильно
    try:
        abuser_id = int(msg.get_args())
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return await msg.reply("Укажи ID пользователя.")

    banned_users.add(abuser_id)
    await msg.reply(f"Пользователь {abuser_id} заблокирован.")

AttributeError: module 'dp' has no attribute 'message'
Tried to reinstall the module, but that didn't help.
I really do appreciate for the answers.

Your code doesn't try to access a message attribute anywhere. Did you mean message_handler, or did you omit the code that actually produces the error? Please provide a [mcve].
